# Do Google Cloud Tasks Delete themselves once they have executed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

In my application, I have implemented Google Tasks so that my users can receive notifications on when their `ToDo` item is due.

My main issue is that when my Cloud Task fires, I noticed that I still see it located in my Cloud Task Console. So, do they delete themselves once they are fired? For my application, I want the cloud tasks to delete themselves once they are done.

I noticed in the documentation this line `you can also fine-tune the configuration for the task, like scheduling a time in the future when it should be executed or limiting the number of times you want the task to be retried if it fails.` The thing is, my task is not failing and yet I see the number of `retries` at 4.

`firebase cloud functions`

```js
exports.firestoreTtlCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const payload = req.body;
        let entry = await (await admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).get()).data();
        let tokens = await (await admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${payload.uid}`).get()).get('tokens')
        await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
            tokens,
            notification: {
                title: "App",
                body: entry['text']
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            log('Successfully sent message:')
            log(response)
        }).catch((error) => {
            log('Error in sending Message')
            log(error)
        })
        const taskClient = new CloudTasksClient();
        let { expirationTask } = admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).get()
        await taskClient.deleteTask({ name: expirationTask })
        await admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).update({ expirationTask: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() })
        res.status(200)
    } catch (err) {
        log(err)
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: The task will no longer appear in the queue after it has run. You don't need to explicitly delete it. You can enable the logs for the queue and see if that provides more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task can be deleted if it is scheduled or dispatched. A task cannot be deleted if it has completed successfully or permanently failed according to this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/1.6.1/v2beta2.CloudTasksClient.html#deleteTask).

- The task attempt has succeeded if the app's request handler returns
  an HTTP response code in the range [200 - 299].
- The task attempt has failed if the app's handler returns a non-2xx
  response code or Cloud Tasks does not receive response before the
  deadline which is :

1. For HTTP tasks, 10 minutes. The deadline must be in the interval [15
   seconds, 30 minutes]
2. For App Engine tasks, 0 indicates that the request has the default
   deadline. The default deadline depends on the [scaling type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) of
   the service: 10 minutes for standard apps with automatic scaling, 24
   hours for standard apps with manual and basic scaling, and 60
   minutes for flex apps.

- Failed tasks will be retried according to the [retry
  configuration](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues#Queue.FIELDS.retry_config). Please check your queue.yaml file for the retry
  configuration set and if you want to specify and set them as per your
  choice follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#retry).

The task will be pushed to the worker as an HTTP request. **If the worker or the redirected worker acknowledges the task by returning a successful HTTP response code ([200 - 299]), the task will be removed from the queue as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#httprequest).** If any other HTTP response code is returned or no response is received, the task will be retried according to the following:

- User-specified throttling: retry configuration, [rate limits](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues#Queue.FIELDS.rate_limits), and
  the [queue's state](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues#Queue.FIELDS.state).
- System throttling: To prevent the worker from overloading, Cloud
  Tasks may temporarily reduce the queue's effective rate.
  User-specified settings will not be changed.

Comment: Thank you! I found that I did not return a res.send(200) once I executed the task. This was the issue and now it is working properly.

Comment: That's great.. !